# Jenkins with Powershell - Creating VM

Tags: powershell, jenkins

Started to learn about Jenkins today and I want to do a little project.

Trying to create Job that will "Ask" for VM name and How much RAM user want and deploy the VM.

I'm Using "Choice Parameter" with number 4 , 8

[image]

and the script in the powershell is

```
New-VM -Name $env:Vm_Name -MemoryStartupBytes $env:ram"GB" -BootDevice VHD -NewVHDPath "C:\Users\Itay\Desktop\vm-test\$env:Vm_Name.vhdx" -Path C:\Users\Itay\Desktop\vm-test  -NewVHDSizeBytes 30GB -Generation 2
```

Connect-VMNetworkAdapter -VMName $env:Vm_Name  -SwitchName $env:NIC

I Also tried to do something like this

```
$number = $env:ram 
$integer =  [int]$number
New-VM -Name $Vm_Name -MemoryStartupBytes $integer"gb" -BootDevice VHD -NewVHDPath "C:\Users\Itay\Desktop\vm-test\$Vm_Name.vhdx" -Path C:\Users\Itay\Desktop\vm-test  -NewVHDSizeBytes 30GB -Generation 2
```

but still getting error

```
New-VM : Cannot bind parameter 'MemoryStartupBytes'. Cannot convert value "4gb" to type "System.Int64". Error: "Input
```

or error :

```
Cannot convert value "4096mb" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."
```

At C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\jenkins9080442734241450545.ps1:3 char:2

- $integer =  [int]$ramgb

or :

```
    New-VM : Failed to modify device 'Memory'.
Invalid startup memory amount assigned for '007'.
'007' failed to modify device 'Memory'. (Virtual machine ID 5EB708B9-49D9-4BD3-AC5A-4678B771AA35)
Invalid startup memory amount assigned for '007'. The minimum amount of memory you can assign to this virtual machine 
is '32' MB. (Virtual machine ID 5EB708B9-49D9-4BD3-AC5A-4678B771AA35)
```

just want to do a choice for user to choose how much ram to allocate to the VM

Can someone please help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/new-vm?view=win10-ps#parameters) says for parameter `-MemoryStartupBytes`:

> Specifies the amount of memory, in bytes, to assign to the virtual
> machine.
>
> Type: Int64

Strings like "4gb" or "4096mb" are not convertible to `Int64`. You have do it on your own, which is quite easy when we assume that user can choose only GB values.

1 GB = 1024 MB = 1024 * 1024 KB = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 Byte

```
$bytes = [Int64] $env:ram * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 
New-VM -Name $Vm_Name -MemoryStartupBytes $bytes -BootDevice VHD -NewVHDPath "C:\Users\Itay\Desktop\vm-test\$Vm_Name.vhdx" -Path C:\Users\Itay\Desktop\vm-test  -NewVHDSizeBytes 30GB -Generation 2
```

We convert the string variable `$env:ram` to `Int64`, by placing the type in square brackets in front of the variable, which is called the [cast operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#long-description). Cast operator has higher [precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operator_precedence?view=powershell-7.1#long-description) than arithmetic operators, so PS will first convert the string before it continues with the multiplications.